# Birthday problem (combinatorics), without using inverse solution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

There is that classic question about how many people in a room is required so that at least one pair of people share a birthday, with > 50% probability, the answer is 23. The standard textbook solution is to solve it using:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{At least one shared birthday}\right) = 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(\text{zero shared birthdays}\right)$$

Since the probability of zero shared birthdays is easier to calculate/derive. From what I know, this is calculated as the series:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{zero shared birthdays}\right)=\frac{365-1}{365}\times\frac{365-2}{365}\times\ldots\times\frac{365-22}{365}$$

the above makes sense, because for each successive person in the group, they can't share any birthday with any previous person, so the number of available days diminishes by 1 each time.

However, I am really struggling to derive $\mathbb{P}\left(\text{At least one shared birthday}\right)$, without using the inverse. Some sort of recursion/series is the way to go, something like:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{23 people share at least 1 birthday}\right)=x+\mathbb{P}\left(\text{22 people share at least 1 birthday}\right)$$

I believe the base cases are:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{1 person share a birthday}\right)=0$$
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\text{2 person share a birthday}\right)=1/365$$

Can someone help me derive it, perhaps by spelling out the series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, just take $$p_1=0\quad \quad p_n=p_{n-1}+\frac {n-1}{365}\times (1-p_{n-1})$$

The logic being: in order to have at least one pair with $n$ people, you must either have a pair with the first $n-1$ of them, or you must have no pair with the first $n-1$ but the $n^{th}$ person must match one of the prior $n-1$ birthdays.  And of course these two events are mutually exclusive.

Comment: pretty intense, I think it makes sense

Comment: correct answer, but I guess I don't quite understand how the OR here gets rid of the extra intersection of the 2 events? usually there's a subtraction component in the formula, aka `P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)`

Comment: @AlexanderMills   There is no intersection, since my second event presupposes that the first does not occur.

Comment: yeah hmmm, I guess you're right, then it begs the question why we don't need the intersection in this case, something in my mind tells me the extra intersection should actually be counted, but I guess that doesn't make sense. thanks for the answer.

Comment: Be sure you are clear on the meaning of my two events.  My first event is "there is at least one match amongst the first $n-1$ people".  My second event is "there is no match amongst the first $n-1$ people but the $n^{th}$ person matches one of the first $n-1$".  Those events are clearly mutually exclusive.

Comment: yeah I guess `(n-1)/365` doesn't really mean anything on its own..trippy

Comment: is it true that `P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B)*P(A')`?

Comment: @AlexanderMills  No.  Say $A=B$, and that neither $P(A)$ nor $P(A^c)=0$.